# Installing phantomjs karma launcher in Ubuntu-Docker context

Tags: testing

Karma is a nodejs tool to automate browser testing. It seems that it depends on nodejs plugin fsevents.

But, fsevents is for processing Mac OS X events, therefore I get the error "not supported on your system" for the phantom karma launcher.

Questions I have found on GitHub seem to come from other Mac OS users dealing with upgrading npm.

My question is: how to install karma launcher in headless ubuntu/docker context?

Comment: Mind to share a log ? That's hard to tell which release you're on or whatever could be wrong here, (There's no mention of fsevent in the dependencies on [github](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/blob/master/package.json) so maybe a transient dep somewhere...)

Comment: supposedly, transient, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because fsevents is an optional dependency, the solution has been here:

```
npm install --no-optional karma-phantomjs-launcher
```